# Account Kit App Secret in Facebook developer not displaying

Tags: facebook, account-kit, app-secret

I'm working on an android project and I need to find the **Account Kit App Secret** to **configure** the application login function. When I select account kit settings and then it shows "**Account Kit is no longer available to new developers**". My previous applications still working and I never faced this kind of problem before. I'm struggling to find a way to solve this matter. Appreciate your help for this.

[image: Image : Account Kit is no longer available to new developers]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook stopped integrating new apps. I'm facing this exact problem at the moment. Here's a blog post from facebook developer page~

> ## Account Kit services no longer available starting in March
>
> Starting in March of next year, we will no longer offer the app login
> product Account Kit. In order to provide our valued developers and
> partners with adequate time to prepare for the change, the deprecation
> will occur in multiple phases:
>
> - September 9, 2019: Account Kit will stop integrating with new apps. Existing integrations will continue to function normally.
> - December 9, 2019: If you’re using SMS as a means to verify phone numbers, the daily SMS limit will be reduced to a maximum of 1,000
>   messages per app ID per day.
> - March 9, 2020: Account Kit will no longer be available for developers and partners.
> - June 2020: Developers and partners will have until this date to retrieve data and information from the Facebook platform unless they
>   initiate deletion before the deprecation, in which case their data
>   will be retrievable for 30 days before being deleted from our system.

Reference [here](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/v2/2019/09/09/account-kit-services-no-longer-available-starting-march/)!